# Memory Map How is stack laid and What is the bounary of stack

Tags: memory, stack

Hi I was reading about memory map and looking for stack and this question came in to my mind that as **stack starts from the end of memory But what actually is end of the memory** is it physically the last Address of memory if so then for 32-Bit OS and architecture each program should allocate 4GiB of memory. MMU and virtual memory plays a role?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Addresses seen by the processor are *always* virtual addresses. Hence, end of memory is end of virtual memory. You can have very large addresses as 2^32-x, but they are virtual addresses.

The OS allocates physical pages required by the process. So it will allocate pages for the text, data and heap sections of the process at the lower end of virtual addresses and for the stack at the upper end. The OS creates equivalences between virtual and physical addresses in the page table. This way, the upper virtual addresses that contain the stack will be mapped to physical addresses at any position.

Between the data and heap sections and the stack, there is a large amount of unused free virtual memory that is not allocated by the OS. So there is no risk to have 4GB allocated to the process.

Comment: If that so then for 64Bit OS tremendous amount of Virtual RAM would be available but after all it Virtual so it doesn't make any difference plus does this mean that stack in physical memory is laid linearly or some other form managed by MMU.